# No edge html header

Tags: html, toolbars

I have just started a project for school and need to make a nice looking webpage. I would like to add a toolbar at the top of the page. One that goes all the way to the edge of a webpage. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

For quick and easy styling of a web page I would look at [twitter bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Specifically look at components -> navbar

Comment: This is not quite what I was looking for. The toolbar at the top of that website is exactly what I am looking to make.